# unexpected behaviour when orientation changes from portrait to landscape mode

Tags: android

I have the following manifest file for my app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.netserv.Pungry"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:maxSdkVersion="17"
        android:minSdkVersion="5" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <!-- <meta-data -->
    <!-- android:name="ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS" -->
    <!-- android:value="true" /> -->

    <meta-data
        android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID"
        android:value="a150cb2e31846cf" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/bghomescreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.netserv.Pungry.Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LocationbyCities" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".General" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RestaurantsList" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Quickbite" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AdvanceSearch" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SelectMenu" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RestaurantDetails" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout" />

        <receiver android:name=".UpdateReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I load the app to device it is working fine in portrait mode. But when i change from portrait to landscape mode it is transisting to some different activity which is not the correct one and some times the app itself will close.

I have defined layout's in layout for portrait and layout-land for landscape mode.

I don't want to fix the orientation to portrait mode.

Comment: First thing you should do is be sure to add logging statements to all your activities so you can see what the app is doing and then try to figure out why.  You said it 'sometimes' crashes.  So try adding logging and post your logcat output if possible.

Comment: show us the activity code also.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding these two methods. It had solved my problem.

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        webView.saveState(outState);            
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle inState) {
        webView.restoreState(inState); 
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(inState);
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think this will help. Because he needs to store state somehow but in your case - you're doing nothing, just calling parent class methods.

Comment: @TheReader thanks for the answer. but you have set to some webview. i have to set to entire layout r to any particular layout child?. i am new to this so i am asking.

Comment: can u please say what u have edited or can you edit your answer?.

Comment: @user2143817 I had removed  webView.saveState(outState);  and webView.restoreState(inState);  from my code when I pasted here. But added it again in 5 minutes of posting the answer. So that is not visible in Edit history. And I am nt aware about entire layout problem. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Just use the configChange attribute in your all activities

```
<activity
    android:name="com.netserv.Pungry.Home"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChange="orientation|screenSize" > <!-- like this use this attribute in all activities -->
```

Comment: it will not work when i change from portrait to landscape. it will retain the portrait mode screen only when i rotate to landscape mode.